# My cat isn't eating, drinking, or playing. What might be wrong?

Tags: cats, behavior, multi-pet-families

My cat Mister Demeanor has been really playful, he always eats and every time I eat he wants some of what I have. Recently, I left to go to D.C. for three days. When I came back, he was acting a little strange. He hides in dark places, he is not eating (he chooses to sit by his food bowl without eating or drinking) and every time his brother Tiger wants to play he just walks away. Mister Demeanor is around 2-3 months old. I need to help him. What might be going on?

Comment: Please take him to a vet immediately. Those symptoms could indicate a serious illness.

Answer (score 7):

Take him to the vet. Those symptoms -- hiding in dark places, losing interest in food, playing and love -- are very common in sick cats.

Answer (score 1):

He might just be depressed. Since you left when he loved you, he might just be sad.

Although they are independent creatures, they still need someone to fill their bowls, play with, and socialize with.

Did you hire a pet sitter or ask a friend to check on him? Pets need someone if you're gone that long. Please add that information to the question.

Also, it can be a sign of illness, anxiety, aggression, or something else bad. It can also be a sign of pica, an illness that can affect them mentally.

Those are some examples of why this might be happening. Just take him to the vet just in case.